# remember checkbox and radio button state after page reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am making a filter with jQuery and Laravel (PHP). It filters the data when I click the checkbox or radio button but, if I click checkbox or radio button and refresh the page the state of checked checkbox or radio button will no longer remain. I want the checked state to remain even after the page reloads.

This is my code.

```
<div class="search">

    <input type="radio" name="expertise[]" value="backend" />programmer
    <input type="radio" name="expertise[]" value="frontend" />programmer

</div>
<div class="avail">
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="available[]" value="20" />20
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox"  name="available[]" value="30" />30
    </p>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
<script>
    var expertise = [];
    var  available = [];

    $(document).on('change', 'input[name="expertise[]"], input[name="available[]"]', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        types = []; 
        available = [];
     

        if (document.location.href.indexOf('filter') > -1) {
            var url = '../developers/filter?type=dev';
        } else {
            var url = '/developers/filter?type=dev';
        }

        $('input[name="type[]"]:checked').each(function() {
            expertise.push($(this).val());
            url = url + '&expertise=' + $(this).val();
        });
        $('input[name="available[]"]:checked').each(function() {
            available.push($(this).val());
            url = url + '&available=' + $(this).val();
        });
     

        if (document.location.href.indexOf('filter') > -1) {
            $.get('../developers/filter', {
                type: 'dev',
                expertise: expertise,
                available: available,
               
            }, function(markup) {
                $('.dev-holder').html(markup);
            });
        } else {
            $.get('developers/filter', {
                type: 'dev',
                expertise: expertise,
                available: available,
               
            }, function(markup) {
                $('.dev-holder').html(markup);
            });
        }
        window.history.pushState("", "", url);
    });

</script>
```

Laravel controller

```
public function search(Request $request)
{

    $type = $request->get('expertise'); 
    $availability = $request->get('available');
  
  
  $url = 'filter';

    $users = User::where('type','dev')->where('is_approved', '=', 1);
    if (!empty($type)) {
            $users = $users->where('expertise','dev');
    }
        $users->when($availability, function ($query, $availability ) {
            return $query->where(function ($whereQuery) use ($availability ) {
                foreach ($availability as $item) {
                    $whereQuery->orWhere('avaibility', 'LIKE', $item); 
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already pushing things to the URL so when you load the page you can check the url query string for what's set or not.

```
$(function () {
    var urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search); 
    if (urlSearchParams.get('expertise[]')) {
        $('input[name="expertise[]"][value="'+urlSearchParams.get('expertise[]')+'"]').prop('checked', true);
    }
    urlSearchParams.getAll('available[]').forEach(function (val) {
       $('input[name="available[]"][value="'+val+'"]').prop('checked', true);
    });
});
```

Note that the [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) needs to be polyfilled in IE

This can also be achieved via the HTML and Laravel:

```
<div class="expertise">

    <input type="radio" name="expertise[]" id="backend" value="backend" 
{{in_array('backend', request()->input('expertise',[])) ? 'checked' : ''}} />Backend
    <input type="radio" name="expertise[]" id="frontend" value="frontend" 
 {{in_array('frontend', request()->input('expertise',[])) ? 'checked' : ''}}/>Frontend

</div>
<div class="availability">
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="available[]" value="above30"
        {{in_array('above30', request()->input('available',[])) ? 'checked' : ''}}
        />Above 30 hrs/week
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox"  name="available[]" value="below30"
        {{in_array('below30', request()->input('available',[])) ? 'checked' : ''}}
        />Below 30 hrs/week
    </p>
</div>
```

This is assuming you have this HTML in a .blade.php file

Comment: thanks @apokryfos, on using this {{in_array('backend', request()->input('expertise',[])) ? 'checked' : ''}}  I got error in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given

Comment: when i first click the backend option i will have some params like type, expertise and tags in url. when i click the first option backed and reload the page I get type=device&expertise=backend&tags=       these in url on        alert(urlSearchParams)

Comment: I was confused because `expertise` is named in the HTML as `expertise[]` implying an array but it's only sent as a single value. Changing the `in_array` to `request()->input('expertise') === 'backend') ? 'checked' : ''` would probably fix that

Comment: thanks @apokryfos. I have accepted your answer. just one question I have appended %5B%5D in url and If i don't append this in url i get error invalid foreach loop. is there any way to make clean url removing %5B%5D from url

Comment: %5B%5D is `[]` and is the way to get PHP and Laravel to treat the input as an array. If you remove it you can't iterate over the values which is something you have to do to be able to deal with any number of `available` options.

Answer (score 0):

JS/jQuery: Save into localStorage
PHP/Laravel: Save in session,

```php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['vals']) {
    $_SESSION['vals'] = 'default=stuff'
}

$_SESSION['vals'] //access it like this
```

and then you can change it when they submit
,

```js
//set
let values = ["yes"]
localStorage.setItem('vals',JSON.stringify(values))

//retrieve
let result = localStorage.getItem('vals')
result = JSON.parse(result)

//use
if (result[0] = "yes") {
    yourradiothing.checked = true
}
```

You can also store other things.

Answer (score 0):

U can use local storage for saving the state. Suppose if check box is clicked then store it in local storage and if page reloads make a function to extract data from the local storage and apply it.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.